# How to properly access the value of a parameter that is passed by reference to a constructor from standard input?

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am attempting to create a min priority queue, one of the issues I am running into is I cannot figure out how to initialize the value of the parameters I am inputting at the command line... I am getting a seg fault when I try to input the values.

I feel like I am missing something very obvious, but I am at my end wits trying to figure this out. Any help is greatly appreciated as I am pretty new to coding in general. Thank you..

```
    //header file 
   #ifndef __MinPriorityQueue
   #define __MinPriorityQueue

   #include <string>
   #include <list>
   #include <vector>

   using std::vector;
   using std::string;
   using std::list;

class MinPriorityQueue{

    public:
        MinPriorityQueue();                       //constructor
        ~MinPriorityQueue();                      //destructor
        void insert(const string&, int key);      //insert string and key
        void decreaseKey(const string id, int newKey);  //decreases key in minqueu
        string extractMin();                      //extracts the min string

    private:
        void buildMinHeap();     //produces a min heap from an unordered array
        void minHeapify(int i);  //maintain the min-heap property
        int parent(int i);       //returns min value 
        int left(int i);         //returns smaller val
        int right(int i);        //returns larger val

        class Element
        {
            public:
                Element();
                Element(const string& id, int key);
                ~Element();
            private:
                string* id;
                int key;
        };
        vector<Element*>minheap;
};

#endif
```

//.cpp file

```
MinPriorityQueue::Element::Element()
{
    *id="";
    key=0;
}
MinPriorityQueue::Element::Element(const string& i, int k )
{
    *id=i;//segfaults here
    key=k;
}
```

//main.cpp

```
#include "minpriority.h"
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main(){
    char command='w';
    cin>> command;
    MinPriorityQueue minQue;
    while(command!='q'){
        if (command== 'a')
        {
            string id;
            int key;
            cin>>id>>key;
            minQue.insert(id, key);
        }
        else if (command== 'd')
        {
            string id;
            int key;
            cin>>id>>key;
            minQue.decreaseKey(id, key);
        }
        else if (command== 'x')
        {
            cout<<minQue.extractMin()<<endl;
        }
        cin>>command;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why did you make the `id` member a pointer?

Comment: `string* id;` Why are you storing a pointer to string here? That's probably the reason why your program fails.

Comment: my teacher wanted us to do it that way, I thought it was weird too.

Comment: "my teacher wanted us to do it that way". I find it very hard to believe... Did he mention anything about a `const char *`? Remove the pointer from the string and the code works fine.

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos no, she gave us the .h file and the names of the functions

Comment: Well, in that case, the reason your code doesn't work is because you try to assign a value to that pointer through dereferencing `*id = " "` or `*id = i`, when `id` has no memory allocated which means that it cannot be dereferenced. There are multiple ways to "fix" your program.

Comment: Note: Names starting with underscore followed by a uppercase letter and names containing double underscore *anywhere* are *reserved for the impletation* and you are not allowed to create any such names yourself. Your header guard name `__MinPriorityQueue` falls afoul of these rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is because you try to assign a value the pointer `std::string *id` through dereferencing `*id = " "` and `*id = i`, when the pointer `id` has no memory allocated. This means that it cannot be dereferenced.

There are multiple ways to "fix" your program.

**Option 1:** Make `std::string *id` const and assign the address of the `user_id` variable from main.

```
class MinPriorityQueue
{
    private:
        class Element
        {
            private:
                const std::string *id;
                int key;

            public:
                Element(const std::string &i, int k)
                {
                    id = &i;
                    key = k;
                }
                ~Element() = default;
        };
        std::vector<Element*> minheap;

    public:
        void insert(const std::string &s, int k)
        {
            minheap.push_back(new Element(s,k));
        }
};

int main()
{
    MinPriorityQueue minQue;

    std::string user_id = "test";
    minQue.insert(user_id, 2);
}
```

**Option 2:** Allocate memory for the `std::string *id`.

```
class MinPriorityQueue
{
    private:
        class Element
        {
            private:
                std::string *id;
                int key;

            public:
                Element(const std::string &i, int k)
                {
                    id = new std::string(i);
                    key = k;
                }
                ~Element() = default;
        };
        std::vector<Element*> minheap;

    public:
        void insert(const std::string &s, int k)
        {
            minheap.push_back(new Element(s,k));
        }
};

int main()
{
    MinPriorityQueue minQue;

    minQue.insert("test", 2);
}
```

**Option 3:** Remove the `const` from the function parameters so that its' address can be assigned to the non-const member pointer.

```
class MinPriorityQueue
{
    private:
        class Element
        {
            private:
                std::string *id;
                int key;

            public:
                Element(std::string &i, int k)
                {
                    id = &i;
                    key = k;
                }
                ~Element() = default;
        };
        std::vector<Element*> minheap;

    public:
        void insert(std::string &s, int k)
        {
            minheap.push_back(new Element(s,k));
        }
};

int main()
{
    MinPriorityQueue minQue;

    std::string user_id = "test";
    minQue.insert(user_id, 2);
}
```

**Option 4** (and my personal favorite): Convert the `std::string *id;` pointer to a normal string `std::string id;`.

ps. With the pointer method your default constructor should either allocate memory and initialize the string to an empty string `std::string *id = new std::string("");` or define it as a null pointer `std::string *id = nullptr;`.

Hope this helps.